# Is there a function to randomly assign users into a control & experiment group (more than once) using BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, experimental-design

I can do this for the first time using `FARM_FINGERPRINT(value)` and `MOD` to split my users into two groups but next time I want to run an experiment I need to reassign users to groups **randomly**. Is there a way to do this within BigQuery SQL? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [RAND](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#rand) function something like below. It will reassign the users into groups randomly every time you run it.

```
SELECT username,
       CASE WHEN RAND() < 0.5 THEN 'Control' ELSE 'Experiment' END AS groupname
FROM your-users
```

If you want to deliberately skew the proportions which go into either group, then change the 0.5 to another value between 0 and 1.